# Topological Proof that every Interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

First, the definition of a connected set:

> **Definition:** A topological space is connected if, and only if, it cannot be divided in two
>   nonempty, open and disjoint subsets, or, similarly, if the empty set and the whole set are the 
>   only subsets that are open and closed at the same time.

I don't understand some points in the following proof, that every interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected.

Suppose $I = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $A$ and $B$ are both non-empty and open in the subspace-topology of $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Choose $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ and suppose $a < b$. Let $s := \mathrm{inf}\{ x \in B ~|~ a < x \}$. Then in every neighborhood of $s$ there are points of $B$ (because of the definition of the infimum), but also of $A$, **then if not $s = a$, then $a < s$ and the open intervall $(a,s)$ lies entirely in $A$**. And so $s$ cannot be an inner point of $A$ nor $B$, but this is a contradiction to the property that both $A$ and $B$ be open and $s \in A \cup B$.

With the bold part, I have a problem, why it follows that $(a,s)$ lies entirely in $A$ and it that case it must be that $A = (a,s)$, or not?

Answer (score 6):

The following steps lead to a solution:

***Exercise 1***: Let us *assume* that we have proved $I=[0,1]$ is connected. Prove that as a *consequence* $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b],[a,b]$ are connected for any real numbers $a$ and $b$. (*Hint*: A homeomorphism preserves connectedness and an arbitrary union of connected subspaces with a point in common is connected.)

We have reduced the problem to proving the connectedness of the interval $I=[0,1]$.

**Theorem** The interval $I=[0,1]$ is connected.

*Proof*. Let us assume, for a contradiction, that $I=A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint non-empty closed subspaces of $I$. The function $f:A\times B\to I$ given by the rule $f(a,b)=\left|a-b\right|$ is continuous as it is the restriction of the metric $d:I\times I\to I$ to the subspace $A\times B$. The product $A\times B$ is compact by the compactness of $I$ and an elementary result in point-set topology. The function $f$ is non-zero because $A\cap B=\emptyset$. In particular, there exist $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $f(a,b)$ is a minimum value of $f$. If $a<b$ (as we may assume without loss of generality), then there exists $c\in I$ such that $a<c<b$ by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. If $c\in A$, then $f(c,b)<f(a,b)$ and if $c\in B$, then $f(a,c)<f(a,b)$; either case is a contradiction. Therefore, $I=[0,1]$ is connected. **Q.E.D.**

Of course, the proof above assumes the compactness of $I$. Conversely, the following exercise is relevant in this connection:

***Exercise 2***: Find a proof of the compactness of $I$ *using the connectedness of $I$*. (*Hint*: Choose an open cover of $I$ and let $X=\{x\in I:[0,x]\text{ has a finite subcover}\}$. Prove that $X$ is open and closed in $I$.)

Of course, we cannot use ***Exercise 2*** and the theorem above to answer the question as this would be circular reasoning.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Stefan For exercise 1 it may be helpful to think about the equation of a straight line.

Answer (score 5):

If not $s = a$, then $a<s$ because $s$ is the infimum of a set of elements all larger than $a$.

The entire interval $(a, s)$ must be in $A$ because of how $s$ was chosen. The number $s$ has been chosen so that it is smaller than any element in $B$ greater than $a$, so there can't be any elements of $B$ in the interval $(a, s)$, and since $A$ and $B$ between them contain all of $I$, $(a, s)$ must be completely within $A$.

The crux of the proof is that with this $s$ as chosen (and exisiting, by Archimedes' lemma), it can't be in neither $A$ nor $B$, but at the same time it has to be in one of them, since $A$ and $B$ together cover the whole of $I$. Thus we have a contradiction, and we know that our assumption must be wrong, namely that $I$ can be written as the union of two nonempty, disjoint open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $I$ is an interval. Suppose that $I$ is disconnected. Then there exists two disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ in $I$ such that $I=A \cap B.$ Let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Without loss of generality, we assume that $a < b$.

Let $\alpha = sup \{ x | a \le x \text{ and } x \in A \}.$ Let $\beta =inf \{ x| x \le b \text{ and } x \in B \}.$ By least upper and lower bound property, both $\alpha $ and $\beta$ exist. if $ \alpha \ne \beta $, then there exists $x \in I$ such that $\alpha < x < \beta .$  But this would mean that $I$ is not the union of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $I$ should be union of $A$,$B$.